# how to get expiration date from an item in C#

Tags: c#, date, time

1. I need to remove any user in a user list, that has expired. If expiredDate property of User class is empty or greater than today, the user should be added to the list.
2. The user list is read from a SQL database. If property expiredDate is empty in the database then it will take the default value like ({0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM}) or {{0001/01/01 12:00:00 AM} depends on the user region setup.
3. The current code that I have bellow will remove all the expired user and also user that has expiredDate empty. But I just want to remove the expired user.

   ```
   private User[] removeExpireUserFromList(User[] List)
   {
       User[] result = null;
       int i = 0;
       foreach (var item in List)
       {
           if (item.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Today)
           {
               result[i] = item;
               i++;
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue)

Comment: thank you that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If db column for ExpirationDate is nullable than you need to define ExpirationDate type as nullable in C# code: "DateTime?". After that, it will be read from db as null and you will need to check it as follows:

```
if (item.ExpirationDate == null || item.ExpirationDate < DateTime.Today)
```